# How to use ROLLING in Python ? Error : ValueError: window must be an integer 0 or greater

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code :

```
DF['AA'].rolling('90D').apply(calc_performance)
```

Where `calc_performance`

```
def calc_performance(x):
    if len(x) < 3:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return (x[-1] / x[0]) - 1
```

But it does throw an error :

```
ValueError: window must be an integer 0 or greater
```

My Dataframe is made as follow :

```
               AA  
2009-12-31     107.50     
2010-01-04     106.40    
2010-01-05     102.50     
2010-01-06     106.90     
2010-01-07     104.40   
...               ...   
2023-03-01     121.08   
2023-03-02     124.12     
2023-03-03     122.52   
2023-03-06     128.19    
2023-03-07     133.33
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What's the data type of your index? for rolling datetime related rolling operations - the index needs to be of a datetime type

Comment: @AsishM. It should be date. How can I check it ?

Comment: `df.index.dtype`

Comment: @AsishM. You were right, i converted it to datetime and now it does work

Answer (score -5):

You are trying to pass the string value `"90D"` as the window size which is causing the error (see the use of .rolling() explained in [this blog](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-rolling/)). You can fix this by passing a numerical value instead, for example:

```
DF['AA'].rolling(90).apply(calc_performance)
```

Comment: Can you please delete this answer which is not the excepted answer so I can delete my post  ?